# jQuery, странное поведение .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Столкнулся с проблемой не совсем корректного (в моём понимании) исполнения метоа `.each()` в jQuery.

В общем, есть большая табличная форма, куда динамически добавляются строки.
Далее нужно перебрать все `input` в форме, и назначить им соответствующие атрибуты имён, установить номер строки и тд.

Пример того, что добавляется в форму:

```html
    <tr>
                            <td rowspan="4">1</td>
                            <td rowspan = "4"><textarea class = "form-control" data-id = "naim" name = "tovs[0][naim]"></textarea></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">А (до изменения)</td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_at" name = "tovs[0][a_at]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_code" name = "tovs[0][a_code]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_obozn" name = "tovs[0][a_obozn]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_col" name = "tovs[0][a_col]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_price" name = "tovs[0][a_price]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_sum" name = "tovs[0][a_sum]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "a_akc" name = "tovs[0][a_akc]"></td>
                            <td rowspan="4"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Б (после изменения)</td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_past" name = "tovs[0][b_past]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_code" name = "tovs[0][b_code]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_obozn" name = "tovs[0][b_obozn]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_col" name = "tovs[0][b_col]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_price" name = "tovs[0][b_price]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_sum" name = "tovs[0][b_sum]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "b_akc" name = "tovs[0][b_akc]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style = "text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">В ( увеличение )</td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "v_grow" name = "tovs[0][v_grow]"></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "v_sum" name = "tovs[0][v_sum]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "v_akc" name = "tovs[0][v_akc]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style = "text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Г ( уменьшение )</td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "g_um" name = "tovs[0][g_um]"></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><p style = "text-align: center;">X</p></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "g_sum" name = "tovs[0][g_sum]"></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" class = "form-control" data-id = "g_akc" name = "tovs[0][g_akc]"></td>
                        </tr>
```

Пытаюсь перебрать целиком всю таблицу, привязавшись к `textare`, так как для каждой заполняемой "строки" он будет один:

```js
$('textarea').each(function(index) {
  p = $(this).parents('tr');
  p.find('.rowCount').html(index);
  tag = $(this).parents('table').attr('id') + '[' + index + ']';
  $(this).attr('name', tag + '[' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']');
  iter = index;
  $('.lastIns').each(function(index) {
    console.log(index);

    ins = $(this).find('input');
    ins.attr('name', tag + '[' + $(ins).attr('data-id') + ']');
    $(this).removeAttr('class');
  });
});
```

В итоге получается, что вложенная переборка (по input), перебирает разом все поля при первой итерации, и для всех последующих для `input` устанавливает индекc 0, хотя, если следовать логике, то должен быть установлен индекс соответствующе "строки" (что и устанавливается для textarea), однако, туда всегда попадает 0.

В чём может быть проблема? куда копать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `привязавшись к textarea, так как для каждой заполняемой строки он будет один` ...я вижу 4 строки и только 1 `textarea`

Comment: @МихаилРебров, всё верно. У родителя textarea rowspan = 4.  Соответственно, на странице он будет занимать высоту четырёх строк. Последующие ячейки - по одной.

Comment: Что там в .lastIns? В html-коде такого класса нет.

Comment: @Егор Банин, класс lastIns добавляется по клику на кнопку: 
`$('#shfCorAddRow').on('click',function(){

  t = $(this).parents('table'); 
  t.find('.clone1').clone().removeAttr('class').attr('class','lastIns').appendTo(t.find('.corrBody')).show();`

Comment: Окей. Что в .clone1? Что вы итерируете во внутреннем each?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых не забывайте писать let (var), когда объявляете переменную. Js коварен! Он ищет необъявленную переменную
во внешнем скоупе, потом во внешнем скоупе внешнего скоупа и так до самого верха. Если он не нашёл переменную на самом верху,
он создаёт её. Это может приводить к опасным ошибкам.

Попробуйте угадать что сделает код:

```js
function foo() {
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        console.log(bar());
    }

    console.log(i);
}

function bar() {
    i = 100500;
    
    return 'hello';
}

foo();
```

Во-вторых, с jQuery или без него старайтесь разбивать вашу задачу на части, выделяя соответствующие методы.
Тогда код будет гораздо проще.

---

В вашем случае логически связанные куски html никак не объединены. Хорошо было бы это исправить, изменив вёрстку.
Но попробуем расплести ваш код и так (я использую нативный js, вы легко перепишете это на jQuery).

Сперва решим абстрактную проблему. Надо научиться получать все строки таблицы, которые объединяются какой-то ячейкой.
То есть нам нужна функция, которая на вход получит ячейку, а на выход отдаст массив строк, которые эта ячейка объединяет.

```
function getRows(td) {
    let rowspan = td.getAttribute('rowspan');
    let row = td.parentElement;
    let rows = [
        row,
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < (rowspan - 1); ++i) {
        row = row.nextElementSibling;
        rows.push(row);
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Теперь получим id таблицы, он не меняется в цикле, поэтому выбирать его каждый раз не обязательно:

```
const table = document.querySelector('form table'); // уточните селектор в зависимости от вашего html
const tableId = table.getAttribute('id');
```

Теперь выберем textarea и найдём строки таблицы, которые объединяет соответствующая ячейка:

```
let textareas = table.querySelectorAll('textarea'); // обратите внимание, что я ищу не по всему документу, а только в таблице (jQuery тоже так может)
textareas.forEach((textarea, i) => {
    let tag = `${tableId}[${i}]`;

    let textareaId = textarea.dataset.id;  // jQuery тоже так может (https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)
    textarea.setAttribute('name', `${tag}[${textareaId}]`);

    // получаем все строки, которые объединяет ячейка с textarea
    trs = getRows(textarea.parentElement);
    trs.forEach(tr => {
        // для каждой строчки проставим имена input'ам
        let inputs = tr.querySelectorAll('input');
        inputs.forEach(input => input.setAttribute('name', `${tag}[${input.dataset.id}]`));
    });
});
```

Вот в эту сторону вам стоит копать.

---

P.S. А each в jQuery работает предсказуемо хорошо! :-)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, на данный момент пришёл к решению следующему:

```
$('textarea').each(function(index){         
                p = $(this).parents('tr');          
                p.find('.rowCount').html(index);
                tag = $(this).parents('table').attr('id')+'['+index+']';
                $(this).attr('name', tag+'['+$(this).attr('data-id')+']');
                iter = index;                   
        });
        $('.lastIns').find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name', tag+'['+$(this).attr('data-id')+']')
        });
        $('.lastIns').removeAttr('class');
```

Просто вынес вторую переборку наружу. Решение костыльное, как по мне, но работает и ладно.

Comment: tag будет меняться в каждой итерации по textarea. Когда цикл завершится, то в tag будет последнее значение. Это работает, пока у вас только одна textarea.